# JavaFX BufferedImage To Byte And From Byte To Image

Tags: image, javafx, stream, byte

I am trying to create a support remote dekstop application using Robot and it needs a buffered image to be sent to a stream but i have no idea how to convert the image to byte and from byte to image again how can i do that? i am using ObjectOutputStream as the output stream. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, see these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580038/byte-array-to-image-file

Comment: Or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074774/javafx-image-serialization

Comment: I have the image now converted to byte but how i convert the byte back to the image?

Comment: Someone please help me how do i convert a byte that was set like this: Byte byte1 = Byte.decode(image.toString()); back to image?

Comment: I think i found a solution to the problem