# Add Image to custom ArrayList for Serialized Intent

Tags: java, android

Apologies in advance if this seems to convoluted, but this is driving me insane :/

In my MainActivity I've created an ArrayList:-

```
final ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();
```

which I'm filling with objects for a custom class I created called Song:-

```
songs.add(new Song("Highway to Hell", "ACDC", "3:28", "Rock", "Highway to Hell", "1979"));
```

Which get used in a Listview:-

```
SongAdapter adapter = new SongAdapter(this, songs);
final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

These ArrayList objects are used to display some of their information (song and artist) in a ListView in the MainActivity and each view has an onClickListener.

When a ListView TextView is pressed I store the Array position into arrayObject which is of type Song:-

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // get pressed object
            arrayObject = songs.get(position);
        }
    });
```

Then when another button is pressed (again on an onClickListener) I send the current Array Object (arrayObject) to the other Activity:-

```
Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SongDetailsActivity.class);
detailsIntent.putExtra("SongObject", arrayObject);
startActivity(detailsIntent);
```

Which works fine when I implement Serializable on the MainActivity and the Song custom class.

** ISSUE **

I also have an ImageView (which can be one of two source images) that I wish to pass to the other Activity as well so I can set the displayed image on that activity to match the image shown on the MainActivity.

It's adding this ImageView that I can't get to work. I've tried sending it as a Drawable like this (after adding the Drawable method to the custom class):-

```
songs.add(new Song("November Rain", "Guns N' Roses", "8:57", "Rock", "Use Your Illusion I", "1991",getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.playbutton)));
```

which Android Studio seems happy with to compile, but as soon as I run the app and try to change view to the other Activity I get an error:-

```
2018-12-04 08:33:44.453 13324-13324/com.example.android.musicplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.musicplayer, PID: 13324
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.android.musicplayer.Song)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1526)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1474)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:723)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1133)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:763)
    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8655)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3052)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1518)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4507)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4475)
    at com.example.android.musicplayer.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:103)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
```

which is complaining about the serializable object, but I have no idea what is wrong with the serializable object.

I also tried setting it as an ImageView in the custom class and MainActivity, but every way I try to write it Android Studio gives errors and wont even compile.

I'm not sure how is the best way to go about this.

As I mentioned, I just want to pass the current Image being used in the ImageView so I can sync both Activities with the same image. It doesn't matter if it's by reference or the actual image, I just want to get it across to the other activity.

Please let me know if this didn't make sense. 
Thanks

Comment: Drawables can't be serialized. Pass the resource value instead and load the Drawable in the destination Activity.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074774/javafx-image-serialization

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and explanations. I'll have a look at both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put drawable in bundle because it is nor serializable parameter.
i see its a demo app, ill give you a fast solution, but remember to read about serialization.

in the Song object save the name of the drawable, and with this function you can get the drawable by its name (keep it):

```
    public static int getImage(Context context, String imageName) {
        int drawableResourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        return drawableResourceId;
    }
```

Change drawable parameter in your Song class to String and follow this instructions:

```
songs.add(new Song("November Rain", "Guns N' Roses", "8:57", "Rock", "Use Your Illusion I", "1991", "playbutton"));

int resource = getImage(activity, song.getImage());
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(resource);
```

**Changed at the request of the questioner**

i think your Song class looks like that:

```
class Song {
    String name;
    String singer;
    String duration;
    String genre;
    String lyrics;
    String year;
    Drawable image;
}
```

change it to:

```
class Song implements Serializable {
    String name;
    String singer;
    String duration;
    String genre;
    String lyrics;
    String year;
    String image;
}
```

instead

```
new Song("November Rain", "Guns N' Roses", "8:57", "Rock", "Use Your Illusion I", "1991",getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.playbutton));
```

use

```
new Song("November Rain", "Guns N' Roses", "8:57", "Rock", "Use Your Illusion I", "1991", "playbutton");
```

now you can pass the object like that:

```
    Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SongDetailsActivity.class);
    detailsIntent.putExtra("SongObject", arrayObject);
    startActivity(detailsIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't quite understand what this is doing or where things go?

Comment: I added more detailed instructions (Edit the original answer)

Comment: I think I understand; changing the Song Class image variable to a String which will allow the serialization to occur. I then add the function into the destination Activity, which gets called by the "int resource" and then the Image details can be acquired through the following "Drawable" call. A couple of things, 1. android can't resolve 'activity' and 'song', and 2. How does the Song Class know what Image Class it's looking at, at the moment my understanding is that it just has a String referencing nothing? Unless your mention to save the name of the drawable in the Class does this somehow?

Comment: 1. i don't understand the question.
2. i gave you function to get image resource from drawable name, use it.

Comment: Thanks Guy4444, I am working over the solution, it's ended being a pretty substantial change, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Drawables can't be serialized.

The quickest fix is to send the `R.drawable.playbutton` (which is an integer) to the intent - in your case, through the `Song` class. Then in the `SongDetailsActivity` you can load the drawable after retrieving it from the intent with `getResources().getDrawable(...)`.

This is the same thing you would do if you were implementing a Parcelable.

Here is what you should have:

```
//Song class should implement a parcelable
public class Song implements Parcelable{
    //....
    //....
    private int drawable;

    public Song(..., ..., int drawable){
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }

    private Song(Parcel in) {
        //...
        //...
        drawable = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<Song> CREATOR = new Creator<Song>() {
        @Override
        public Song createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Song(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Song[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Song[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        //...
        //...
        dest.writeInt(drawable);
    }

}
```

Add song to array list like this

```
songs.add(new Song("November Rain", "Guns N' Roses", "8:57", "Rock", "Use Your Illusion I", "1991", R.drawable.playbutton));
```

Send arrayList to SongDetailsActivity

```
Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SongDetailsActivity.class);
detailsIntent.putExtra("SongObject", arrayList);
startActivity(detailsIntent);
```

ArrayList is serializable by default but retrieving it from an intent can be tricky, so we had to implement a parcelable on the song so that the `ArrayList` can be retrieved as an `ArrayList` of Parcelables that can be cast to Song.

Take note of the `Creator<Song>` we used when implementing Parcelable in the Song class. It allows us to be able to cast the `Parcelable` back to `Song`.

ArrayList of Objects (other than Integer, String and CharSequence) can only be retrieved from intent via Parcelables. Why? because the Integer, String and CharSequence are serialized by default; Objects aren't.

Get arrayList in the SongDetailsActivity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<Parcelable> songs = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("SongObject");

//retrieve each song
for(Parcelable parcelable : songs){
      Song song = (Song) parcelable;
      //load the drawable now
      getResources().getDrawable(song.drawableInt)
}
```

PS: The snippets above have not been tested since you are implementing with many other parameters. But it should work, if you plug them in correctly.

Any associate object of a serializable object must implement it's own serializable or must contain a `readObject(ObjectInputStream ois)` and `writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos)`, otherwise you'll get a runtime error - which is what happens in your case.

---

**Update based on comments below:**

To get only a Song object in the SongDetailsActivity, you can add a tag to the view that you click in the ListView when rendering from your Adapter's getView like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
   Song song = getItem(position);
   ViewHolder viewHolder;
   if(convertView == null){
     //set viewHolder
   }else{
     viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag(); 
   }
   viewHolder.itemToClick.setTag(R.id.item_id, song);
}
```

Then retrieve Song and send to Activity in your onClick

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Song song = (Song) view.getTag(R.id.item_id);
    if(song != null){
      //Send intent
      //It is cleaner if you do this in the Activity, but for illustration sake
      Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SongDetailsActivity.class);
      detailsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, song);
      startActivity(detailsIntent);
    }
}
```

Then retrieve in your SongsDetailsActivity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Song song = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
//load the drawable now
getResources().getDrawable(song.drawableInt);
```

Comment: I'm getting "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.musicplayer/com.example.android.musicplayer.SongDetailsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.ArrayList.iterator()' on a null object reference", so I gather the object didn't get passed over? Just to restate what I'm doing, I am using an adapter with a ListView and using the position in the onClick to choose the Array position to send. I've shown it in my original post. Could this be causing the problem?

Comment: Okay, if I understand you, you don't need the arrayList in the new Activity? What you only need is the Song object? I'll update my answer if that is the case

Comment: Yes that's correct, just the song object that relates to the TextView that gets pressed in the ListView, so it should be one of the song objects in the arrayList, not the whole array.

Comment: To be clear, do you currently have a hold on the corresponding Song object when you click on the item in the adapter for the ListView?

Comment: The function is:- I click on the TextView in the ListView, which corresponds to a song object (with all the song details and the imaged used, which will be either a play or pause image). Once a song is chosen the user can click to go to the next screen which will show all the song details contained in the song object that got passed. The image state that is passed gets used to display the same image that was in the original activity. So if the user had pressed play (the image would change to pause), that pause image would be passed so the pause image can be displayed in the details activity.

Comment: I need to know if you are using a custom adapter with a viewholder.

Comment: public class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song>, public SongAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Song> nameForArrayOfSongObjects) {
        super(context, 0, nameForArrayOfSongObjects);
    },    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.song_item, parent, false);
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184656/discussion-between-markus-and-caleb-lucas).

Answer (score 1):

Your Song class should be this

```
public class Song implements Parcelable {
    String name;
    String singer;
    String duration;
    String genre;
    String album;
    String year;
    String imagetype;

    public Song() {} //your custom constructor

    protected Song(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        singer = in.readString();
        duration = in.readString();
        genre = in.readString();
        album = in.readString();
        year = in.readString();
        imagetype = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Song> CREATOR = new Creator<Song>() {
        @Override
        public Song createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Song(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Song[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Song[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(singer);
        dest.writeString(duration);
        dest.writeString(genre);
        dest.writeString(album);
        dest.writeString(year);
        dest.writeString(imagetype);
    }
}
```

Then you send a data of the current selected song by click listview

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // get pressed object
            arrayObject = songs.get(position);
            Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SongDetailsActivity.class);
            detailsIntent.putExtra("SongObject", arrayObject);
            startActivity(detailsIntent);
        }
    });
```

You have a data

> new Song("November Rain", "Guns N' Roses", "8:57", "Rock", "Use Your Illusion I", "1991", "sourceone"));

in SongDetailsActivity.class you should check the imagetype

```
Song s = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("SongObject");
if (s.imagetype.equals("sourceone")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbutton);
} else {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.elsebutton);
}
```

Same thing, you need to check imagetype in your adapter if you want to have the same image. Hope it helps.